# How to like a post or a page via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm searching the solution to like a post or a page via Facebook API with a USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

The doc facebook here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes#publish said: `Note: as of Nov 17, 2016 we changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens.` But I want to publish like as user but not page

Then I found another doc facebook here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes#publishing 
but I got an error `{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'PAGE/POST_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.`

Anyone can help, please? Thanks!

Comment: what is the use case for this? why not just let users like a post or a page directly on facebook.com? what´s the benefit for the user if he uses your app to do that?

Comment: @luschn for exemple, my application lists 'TOP 10 public Place' and their posts. I hope that the user can like these posts or follow these places directly in my application when they see them. If not...jump to the facebook page, then like/follow, and then comme back to my application, bad UX, no? :D

Comment: _“But I want to publish like as user but not page”_ – that is simply not possible any more, _because_ of the change they made.

Comment: @CBroe Thx your response :D Another simple question maybe you can help: If there is any API to follow 1 public page (no matter as User or as Page) ?